Date value is coming invalid format when using Partition by Clause in Redshift
I am facing one new problem in redshift. When I am trying with Partition by clause in row_number function, my desired date conversion is coming invalid format.
Ex:
SELECT   
  date_column,
  To_char(To_date(date_column, 'Mon DD, YYYY FMHH12:MI:SS AM'), 'YYYYMMDD') AS date_yyyymmdd,
  Row_number() OVER( partition BY id ORDER BY To_timestamp (last_updated_on, 'Mon DD, YYYY HH24:MI:SS PM' ) DESC ) AS rank
FROM     main_table limit 10

Output:
Jul 28,2017 02:47:26 PM      00170728       1
Aug 09,2017 03:50:00 PM      00170809       1
Sep 07,2017 01:55:00 PM      00170907       1
Sep 13,2017 12:45:00 PM      00170913       1
Sep 20,2017 04:20:00 PM      00170920       1

The 1st column is main date column which directly coming from main_table. 2nd column is converted date column. So, when I am removing partition by condition, the converted date column is coming as expected. But adding partition by column, the desired date format is coming invalid. Can anyone help me on this to resolve.

Perhaps, your query take random rows from main_table - limit 10 without order by. partition by id changes this row set to another. So, date format is coming invalid -> compare differen row sets. Show output with partition and without partition. And include id to output.

I suspect it may be due to your format string being incorrect.  Your date string does not have a space after the comma between the day and the year - "Jul 28,2017 02:47:26 PM".  You format string does - "Mon DD, YYYY FMHH12:MI:SS AM".
I suspect that your data is inconsistent in the addition of this space and that when you add the window function it is changing the top 10 rows.  This window has order by and partition clauses which changes where rows will be in memory when it runs. It is just changing which rows you are seeing.
Removing the space from the format (if it is never there) or adding an additional FM should do the trick if I'm correct - 'Mon DD,FMYYYY FMHH12:MI:SS AM'

Good Catch :) The space was causing the issue.
Thank you very much!
